# Will it be counted as a sin if it happened because of someone else?

Tags: sin

I wanted to know will a person commit any sin because of of someone else be counted as one? I actually got false information from someone about doing a particular act which was sin but he told it wasn't, so will that mean I also commited a sin or only that person?

Answer (score 1):

Your sins are your own. You may be forgiven if you committed your sin in ignorance because Allah is Merciful, but that's not the same as not having committed the sin.

If someone else misguided you, their sins are their own; they may be carrying the sin of misguiding you as well as the burden of any additional sins you caused because of that misguidance, but again that's not the same as you not having committed the sin.

If you have sinned, and you know you have sinned, pray for repentance. Don't waste time trying to blame other people for it, Allah knows what you did and what they did and He is always the most Just of judges.

Comment: Brother/sister you answer less nowadays but when you do they are always on point Masha Allah. 